# Clear webView cookies (Swift)

Tags: swift, cookies, webview, oauth

How can I clear all cookies for few hosts in my webView?
Method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543817/how-to-manage-cookies-with-uiwebview-in-swift) question not working.

I'm trying to work with vk.com oauth and it does not have user-logout method, so deleting cookis is one of existing ways to make other user possible to log in

**Answer is below**

Comment: `let day_url_request = NSURLRequest(URL: day_url,
    cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
    timeoutInterval: 10.0)` Have you tried that with request. Sorry For the first answer, I missed that one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107806/clearing-uiwebviews-cache-in-swift

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I made it by

```
        let cookieJar = NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage()

        for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
           // print(cookie.name+"="+cookie.value)
            cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
        }
```

**Swift 4**

```
func removeCookies(){
    let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared

    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
        cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

Comment: Initialization of immutable value 'cookie' was never used;

Answer (score 12):

One liner in Swift 5

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies?.forEach(HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie)
```

Comment: I tried this line as well as the other options looping through the cookies, and nothing is deleted - any idea what the problem can be?

Answer (score 10):

Nothing above worked for me.
Using the following:

- Swift 5
- Xcode 12.4
- WebKit

Below is the solution worked for me:

```
func removeCookies() {
    HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)
    print("All cookies deleted")

    WKWebsiteDataStore.default().fetchDataRecords(ofTypes: WKWebsiteDataStore.allWebsiteDataTypes()) { records in
        records.forEach { record in
            WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: record.dataTypes, for: [record], completionHandler: {})
            print("Cookie ::: \(record) deleted")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

swift 4

```
func removeCookies(){
    let cookie = HTTPCookie.self
    let cookieJar = HTTPCookieStorage.shared

    for cookie in cookieJar.cookies! {
        cookieJar.deleteCookie(cookie)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`UIWebView` is nearly  deprecated.
So for `WKWebView` instance make this code:

```
let cookieStore = webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore

cookieStore.getAllCookies {
    cookies in

    for cookie in cookies {
        cookieStore.delete(cookie)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By avoiding Force Unwrap

```
private func clearCookie2(){
    let storage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    if let cookies = storage.cookies{
        for cookie in cookies {
            storage.deleteCookie(cookie) 
        }
    }
}
```

And if you want to delete only specific cookie

```
let DOMAIN_NAME = "abc.com"
private func clearCookie(){
    let storage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
    if let cookies = storage.cookies{
        for cookie in cookies {
            if(cookie.domain.contains(DOMAIN_NAME)){
                storage.deleteCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variation to remove based on date. `.distantPast` to remove all

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.removeCookies(since: Date.distantPast)
```